# How to alter and add a datetime2(7) not null field to an already existing table with data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that already has a set of values. Now I have to add a column thats of type `datetime2(7)` which will be not null. I cannot insert `getdate()` as the default value as this can lead to problems. How can I add that column with `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` as the default value?

Comment: I know! :) Thank you but does that make the question vague?

Comment: `default convert(datetime2(7),' 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000')`

Comment: `0001-01-01` is a valid date. Why treat it as a magic date instead of using `NULL`? A `NULL` explicitly means there's no value and doesn't require guessing. In any case yu can add `0001-01-01` or `9999-12-31` as the default value, eg `alter mytable add MyDate datetime2(7) default '0001-01-0')`

Comment: Using `0001-01-01` or `9999-12-31` would make sense for columns specifying a validity range, eg for `ValidSince`, `0001-01-01` is a better choice than `NULL`. For a `BirthDate` though, `0001-01-01` isn't just weird, it results in the weird bugs we hear about in TV every once in a while. People that are 2021 years old, or pensioners whose pension will come in 9999-12-31

Comment: Even for validity dates, i still tend to use `NULL`, @PanagiotisKanavos . If you don't "know" the start/end date, to me `NULL` seems appropriate. Yes, means you need to change your `WHERE`, etc, a little, but still it makes more sense to me to have the validity end date as `NULL` until you know when the actual date will be. But that's more preference than anything.

Comment: @Larnu you are technically right, but until SQL Server does `NULLS FIRST / LAST` properly, that is the only performant solution

Answer (score 0):

Define the `DEFAULT` value and use `WITH VALUES`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewColumn datetime2(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000' WITH VALUES;
```

Though, a default value of `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000` is pretty odd. Seems like, in my opinion, it *should* be `NULL`. `NULL` means an unknown value, and clearly you don't know what the value of these rows should be.